# Docker php nginx mariadb

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and I'm trying to convert my config.php into docker-compose and dockerfile but I can't run a server...

default.conf:

```
upstream php {
        server php:9000;
}

server {
        root /var/www/monsite;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass php;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you say “enter image description here”, we don’t know what the issue is either.  Can you replace that link with a textual description (not an image) in the question itself (not behind a link) of what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't run a server"?

Comment: When I i use the command 'docker-compose up' and then I go to my localhost:8080, it show 403 Forbidden

Comment: Oh, so the server ***is*** running, you just have forbidden access. Can you update your post with the default.conf?

Comment: Yes, you are right haha... sorry
Do you know how to solve the 403 forbidden problem ?

Comment: Sorry, i am new to stack overflow, I had to edit the rest of my code ...